# What happened to Professor X?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Having been reading the X-Men related comics for a few months (from Schism on), I was wondering what happened to Professor X, the mutant most associated with the X-Men?  Is he dead?  What title(s) should I be reading for him?

The [Marvel wiki](http://marvel.com/universe/Professor_X) mentions an abduction on the way to the Shi'ar homeworld, but given the other members of the mission appear to be takng part in AvX I'm guessing that is out of date.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_X) has even less of a mention.

Comment: Wasn't he killed by Prof. Jean Grey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Professor X was ejected from the X-Men by Cyclops after finding out that Xavier had wiped his memories of his brother, Vulcan, and his death, but after the events of the Utopia storyline, Professor X is living back on Utopia.  Since Cyclops is now the leader of the X-Men, Xavier no longer has a major role in events.

Professor X last turned up in Avengers vs X-Men #6 to counsel Cyclops.

The last storyline with Professor X as a regular was X-Men Legacy, though he has made further cameos a few times since.